# Themes missing after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, themes

I recently upgraded my distro (Ubuntu) from 10.04 Lucid Lynx to 12.04 Precise Pangolin.
What happened is all of the themes went missing (there is no dropdown menu in Appearance), and I'm stuck with a custom theme I used under GNOME.

Any way to get the default themes back?

This is my desktop:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install light-themes` should get you the themes back. Have you checked in the `/usr/share/themes/` to verify that they're actually missing, and it's not some other problem?

Also, you should file a bug report about this, as it should not happen.

Comment: This worked. Thanks! What was in /usr/share/themes was some old GNOME themes I had.